# File Permissions keep changing back

Tags: centos, chmod, umask

We have a cent os7 server that recently had a new user added. It seems that during this process permissions were wrongly updated. After I have fixed the permissions to suit the site required permissions it will change back after sometime to the previous permissions. Some times it's changing several times a day.

How I'm changing the permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I'm assuming this is down to a possible `umask` or something along those lines. Though I didn't think `umask` could just reupdate permissions on already existing directories and files.

Comment: Does changing the ownership works? sudo chown

Comment: @SantiagoEchevarria I need to maintain ownership because it's web facing with apache.

Comment: Related: [monitor file permission changes](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/150241)